# How to run a js file from VSCode's builtin Node.js?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

I need to run a js file from the Node.js that is builtin in the Electron which VSCode uses. Currently I am doing that by running a VSCode extension but there ought to be an easier way.

The code below should print the Electron version:

```
console.log(process.versions.electron)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code does not expose functionality that lets users run arbitrary JS and this is unlikely to change. Using an extension is the correct approach